# Android: Dynamically added TextView not wrapping text

Tags: android, xml, textview

Dynamically adding TextViews to this layout results in text not being wrapped.

```
<!-- R.layout.description_card -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout_InfoShow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/table_row_padding_bottom" >

    <TableLayout 
        android:background="@drawable/card_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/TableRow_DescriptionTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/DescriptionTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/page_name_size"
                    android:text="Loading data..." />

        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/DescriptionTitle">

                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout_Description"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <!-- Dynamically added TextView here -->

                </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I dynamically add the TextViews to this layout using these methods:

```
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.description_card, null);
                        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.DescriptionTitle);
                        LinearLayout description = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout_Description);
ArrayList<TextView> textViews = des.getText();
            Iterator<TextView> iter = textViews.iterator();
                 while(iter.hasNext()){
                    TextView textView = iter.next();
                    description.addView(textView); 
                }
```

This results in my textviews not wrapping onto new lines, even though it works perfectly fine if I include the TextView directly in the XML file.

It results in this:
[image: screenshot]

Edit:
TextView layout:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/TextViewDescription"
    style="@style/AppTheme"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:text="Loading data..."
    android:textSize="@dimen/description_size"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set it to multi line.  Try

```
setInputType (InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
```

If you have other InputType attributes, you'll need to "or" them together.

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix the issue. Could it be an issue with the layout widths? (updated main post)

Comment: I think your best bet at this time is to simplify.  For example, try putting a TextView directly in the xml file where you say "dynamically add..." and comment-out your iterator loop.  If you can get this working, then you will be able to start looking at what's different between the two.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to suggest going a completely different direction.  I suspect the problem is that TextView doesn't know how much width it has (because the TableLayout determines that based on what the child views ask for) so it simply puts everything on one line, thinking that's fine.  I'll post a 2nd answer in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

At this part of your code, you are getting your `TextView` array:

```
ArrayList<TextView> textViews = des.getText();
```

And we don't see how those `TextView`'s are created. But I assume you did not set `single_line` or `max_lines` to `TextView`s.

Try this code while adding your `TextView`s to your LinearLayout:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

while (iter.hasNext()) {
    TextView textView = iter.next();
    description.addView(textView, params);
}
```

**Edit:**
Use below layout while creating your `TextView`s(I've removed some attrs and style.):

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/TextViewDescription"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:text="Loading data..."
    android:textSize="@dimen/description_size"/>
```

**Edit2:** Change your `layout_width` param to `wrap_content`. Also see updated param at code above. (This worked for me)

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout_Description"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!-- Dynamically added TextView here -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `TextView textView = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.textview_description, null);
    textView.setText(e.text());` This is what I use to create the TextView. I've added the LayoutParams but i'm still getting the same result.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Params also changed while adding textViews to LinearLayout.

Comment: Okay, so even when I add that TextView inside the LinearView hard coded the text isn't wrapping. I can't figure out why though.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something other than TableLayout.  I'm not very experienced with TableLayout but I think it needs the child views to have relatively short and consistent widths.

Instead, try using LinearLayout, like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout_InfoShow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/table_row_padding_bottom" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DescriptionTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textSize="@dimen/page_name_size"
        android:text="Loading data..." />

    <!-- Dynamically added TextView here -->

</LinearLayout>
```

And add the views with more-or-less the same code you had before.  Note I changed the parent view for supporting the adds -- outerLayout.

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.description_card, null);

TextView outerView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout_InfoShow);
ArrayList<TextView> textViews = des.getText();

Iterator<TextView> iter = textViews.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
  TextView textView = iter.next();
  outerView.addView(textView); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason.

The inflater needed a ViewGroup for the layout params to take effect.
I had to change the way I pass the text through to the iterator but this is basically what needed changing:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) inflater.inflate(text.getViewID(), description, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the problem... 
When you have

```
<TableLayout>
  <TableRow>
    <TextView>

    </TextView>
  </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

to make the text appear without truncation, 
add

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

inside the textview

```
<TextView>

</TextView>
```